# Table-formatted page with HTML5 elements?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email, semantics

Can I use HTML5 elements to outline code on a "page" that uses a table for formatting? For Example:

```
<section id="posts">
  <tr id="posts-title-row">
    <header><td id="posts-title">
      <h2>Latest Posts</h2>
    </td></header>
  </tr>
  <tr id="posts-row">
    <article><td>
      <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
    </td></article>
    <article><td>
      <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
    </td></article>
    <article><td>
      <p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
    </td></article>
  </tr>
</section>
```

In general, I understand that this is extremely poor form, but until email clients (esp. Gmail) support CSS3 formatting of emails, there is little other option, except to use tables to format HTML emails (e.g. newsletters). However for my own semantic peace of mind, I'd like to use < section >, < article > and < header > type elements to organize things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the semantics you care about you could just use the [ARIA roles](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#table-aria-weak) defined for `<section>` and `<article>` on the existing elements:

```
<table id="posts" aria-role="region">
    <tr id="posts-title-row">
        <td id="posts-title" aria-role="banner">
            <h2>Latest Posts</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="posts-row">
        <td aria-role="article">
            <p>
                Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
            </p>
        </td>
        <td aria-role="article">
            <p>
                Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
            </p>
        </td>
        <td aria-role="article">
            <p>
                Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the best method. Email has inconsistencies with common tags like spans, divs and p's. You'd be asking for trouble trying to force semantic tags to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have the elements in the wrong place. They need to be inside the `<td>`s. You also need to wrap the entire table in a `<table>`

```
<section id="posts">
    <table>
        <tr id="posts-title-row">
            <td id="posts-title">
            <header>
                <h2>Latest Posts</h2>
            </header></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="posts-row">
            <td>
            <article>
                <p>
                    Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
                </p>
            </article></td>
            <td>
            <article>
                <p>
                    Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
                </p>
            </article></td>
            <td>
            <article>
                <p>
                    Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
                </p>
            </article></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah, the table is bigger, I have the < table > tags, but I only copy and pasted a chunk of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use HTML5 tags with table formatting as long as your e-mail service accept it. However, you can try using CSS (note that I haven't said CSS3) to give style to your page. And always remember **inline styles**!

Using table formatting in 2013 is like going in carriage to work, but when talking about e-mail services it still being the town sheriff.

Good luck!